# como sumo los datos de una columna en una matriz 3x10

Tags: c

Realizo un programa en el cual lleno 10 datos en 3 filas(10 en cada fila) y necesito sumar cada uno de los 10 datos individualmente. Como se observa en el codigo estoy declarando y encerando la matriz;luego procedo a recoger los datos(sueldos) y lo que necesito es saber como sumar la columna de sueldos de cada sucursal(hay 3 filas, 1 fila por cada sucursal)

```
float A[3][10];
float prA=0,pa_1=0;
int i=0, j=0,k=0;


for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        A[i][j]=0;
        B[i][j]=0;
        
        
    }
    
} 

system("cls");
printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t*****ciudad A*******");
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("\n\tSucursal #%d",i+1);
for(j=0;j<10;j++){
    printf("\nEmpleado #%d ingrese su sueldo: ",j+1);
    scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);

}
```

Comment: No veo por qué necesitas sumar nada si viendo los datos de origen ya sabemos que el resultado va a ser cero.

Comment: tal como dice @PaperBirdMaster haces a[i][j]=0 en vector a y b debes indicar un valor recuerda recorrer fila columna o como quieras el orden pero define bien el recorrido ayúdate de papel y lápiz, siempre es util antes de solo ingresar codigo